# AngularJS checkbox checked disable other checkbox based on value from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

Here i like to explain my problem clearly,

i have list of checkboxes which generate from json file displaying using ng-repeat.

[image: Checkbox list]

above image shows the list of checkbox, now what i need is
by default i need to disable `1BHK,2BHK,3BHK,4BHK,1Room,2Room,3Room,1Bathroom,2Bathroom,3Bathroom`

after selecting `In-depth home cleaning`, i need to enable `1BHK,2BHK,3BHK,4BHK`
In this `1BHK,2BHK,3BHK,4BHK` users is allow to `only one` in this 4 option.

after selecting `Room Cleaning`, i need to enable `1Room,2Room,3Room`
In this `1Room,2Room,3Room` users is allow to `only one` in this 3 option.

after `selecting Bathroom Cleaning,` i need to enable `1Bathroom,2Bathroom,3Bathroom`
In this `1Bathroom,2Bathroom,3Bathroom` users is allow to `only one` in this 3 option.

Below is my code

```
<div class="checkbox">
       <label ng-repeat="specific in specifications">
       <input ng-disabled="specific == '1 BHK'" id="specifications_chk" value="{{specific}}" ng-model="newObject[specific]" type="checkbox">
            {{specific}}
       </label>
</div>
```

Help me am stuck with this, help will be really appreciated

Comment: How about splitting up the different options in sets of [radio buttons](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)? Group them per set, and 90% of your desired functionality is done. `ng-repeat` is nice, but forms like these require a little more attention than just dumping a list of names into an `ng-repeat`.

Comment: i dont know how to do it

Comment: Then that's what you should research. It's near impossible (Possible, but a pain in the ass) to add all those rules to a single repeated element.